# Python Code Error With Input

Tags: python-3.x, input

I Am having a problem with an input code here is the out come of the code

```
Hello World The Game
Youtube: www.youtube.com/user/creepermoon2/
Current Game Version 0.1 Alpha
What Is your name?Josef

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/Game.py", line 25, in <module>
Name = input ("What Is your name?")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Josef' is not defined
```

The code is

```
#This is a simple video game created by CreeperMoon2
#PROGRAMING NOTES

#to wait use time.sleep(SECONDS)
#
#
#
#

#VARIABLES
GameVrsn = 0.1
#VARIABLES

#IMPORTED CLASSES
import time
import os
#IMPORTED CLASSES

print "Hello World The Game"
time.sleep(5)
print "Youtube: www.youtube.com/user/creepermoon2/"
time.sleep(5)
print ("Current Game Version 0.1 Alpha")
time.sleep(5)
Name = input ("What Is your name?")
```

I really have no idea how to fix this i got this out of a tutorial for python 3 it may be incorrect but i don't know how to fix it please respond quickly

Comment: One quick thing i wanted to add is that it will do this with any name

Comment: yes i am using pyton 3.3.3 inerpreter

Comment: No the coding is working i got the download link from www.python.org/donwload/ and i got 3.3.3

Comment: wait a minuete what the crap i clicked on the 3.3.3 download and it installed 2.7.5? well thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you think you are running the 3.x interpreter you are actually using the 2.x one, because

```
print "Hello World The Game"
```

would be an error with python 3. (`print` is a function there: `print("Hello World The Game")`)

In Python 2 you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Your code is a mix of Python 2 and 3 syntax and would not work on either without error.

Comment: Just want to say the print function was working the input was not and for some reason it installed 2.7.5

Comment: why wont this input line work?

PlrAge = int(raw_input("How old are you WARNING DO NOT PUT DOWN LETTERS!"))

Comment: @CreeperMoon2 Please create a new question. This has nothing to do with this one here.